# Writing a c# class that has enum like constraint while behaving like string

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Following This post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630803/associating-enums-with-strings-in-c-sharp/56482413?noredirect=1#comment107635743_56482413

I wanted to go further as it didn't quite fully met my needs for a Enum like Class that would act as string I ended-up with a solution that allows me to do the following:

```
   string test1 = TestEnum.Analyze;  //test1 == "ANALYZE"
   string test1bis = (string)TestEnum.Analyze; //test1bis == "ANALYZE"
   TestEnum test2 = "ANALYZE";  //test2 == {ANALYZE}
   TestEnum test3 = "ANYTHING"; //test3 == null
```

As seen below in the unitTests all these work fine with this:

```
 public class TestEnum : EnumType<TestEnum> 
    {
        public static TestEnum Analyze { get { return new EnumType<TestEnum>("ANALYZE"); } }
        public static TestEnum Test { get { return new EnumType<TestEnum>("TEST"); } }

        public static implicit operator TestEnum(string s) => (EnumType<TestEnum>) s;
        public static implicit operator string(TestEnum e) => e.Value;
    }
```

I can't decide if this solution is elegant or incredibly stupid, It seems to me probably unnecessary complex and I might be messing a much easier solution in any case it could help someone so I'm putting this here.

```
 //for newtonsoft serialization
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EnumTypeConverter))]
    public  class EnumType<T>  where T : EnumType<T> , new()
    {
        public EnumType(string value= null)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        //for servicestack serialization
        static  EnumType()
        {

                JsConfig<EnumType<T>>.DeSerializeFn = str =>
                {
                    return (T)str ;
                };
                JsConfig<EnumType<T>>.SerializeFn = type =>
                {
                    return type.Value;
                };

                JsConfig<T>.DeSerializeFn = str =>
                {
                    return (T)str;
                };
                JsConfig<T>.SerializeFn = type =>
                {
                    return type.Value;
                };


        }
        protected string Value { get; set; }


        public static T Parse(string s)
        {
            return (T)s;

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value;
        }

        public static EnumType<T> ParseJson(string json)
        {
            return (T)json;
        }


        public static implicit operator EnumType<T>(string s)
        {
            if (All.Any(dt => dt.Value == s))
            {
                return new T { Value = s };
            }
            else
            {
                var ai = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient(Connector.tconfiguration);
                ai.TrackException(new Exception($"Value {s} is not acceptable value for {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType}, Acceptables values are {All.Select(item => item.Value).Aggregate((x, y) => $"{x},{y}")}"));
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static implicit operator string(EnumType<T> dt)
        {
            return dt?.Value;
        }

        public static implicit operator EnumType<T>(T dt)
        {
            if (dt == null) return null;
            return new EnumType<T>(dt.Value);
        }


        public static implicit operator T(EnumType<T> dt)
        {
            if (dt == null) return null;
            return new T { Value = dt.Value };
        }

        public static bool operator ==(EnumType<T> ct1, EnumType<T> ct2)
        {
            return (string)ct1 == (string)ct2;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(EnumType<T> ct1, EnumType<T> ct2)
        {
            return !(ct1 == ct2);
        }


        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                if(obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
                {
                    return Value == (string)obj;
                }

                return Value == obj as T;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }



        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Value) ? Value.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<T> All
         => typeof(T).GetProperties()
           .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T))
           .Select(x => (T)x.GetValue(null, null));


        //for serialisation
        protected EnumType(SerializationInfo info,StreamingContext context)
        {
            Value = (string)info.GetValue("Value", typeof(string));
        }
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Value",Value);

        }


    }
```

Here are the unit tests:

```
 [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTestEnum
    {
        Connector cnx { get;set; }
        private class Test
        {
            public TestEnum PropertyTest { get; set; }
            public string PropertyString { get; set; }
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            typeof(EnumType<>)
               .Assembly
               .GetTypes()
               .Where(x => x.BaseType?.IsGenericType == true && x.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EnumType<>))
               .Each(x =>
                System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(x.BaseType.TypeHandle)

               );
            cnx = new Connector(); 
        }
        [TearDown]
        public void Clear()
        {
            cnx.Dispose();
        }
        [Test]
        public void EqualsString()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(TestEnum.Analyze, TestEnum.Analyze);
            Assert.AreEqual(TestEnum.Analyze,"ANALYZE");
            Assert.IsTrue("ANALYZE" == TestEnum.Analyze); 

            Assert.IsTrue("ANALYZE".Equals(TestEnum.Analyze));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Casts()
        {

            string test1 = TestEnum.Analyze;
            string test1bis = (string)TestEnum.Analyze;
            TestEnum test2 = "ANALYZE";
            TestEnum test3 = "NAWAK";

            Assert.AreEqual("ANALYZE", test1);
            Assert.AreEqual("ANALYZE", test1bis);
            Assert.IsTrue(test2 == TestEnum.Analyze);
            Assert.IsTrue(test2.Equals(TestEnum.Analyze));
            Assert.AreEqual(test3, null);

        }

        [Test]
        public void Deserializations()
        {

            new List<TestEnum>
            {
                (TestEnum)ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString("\"ANALYZE\"", typeof(TestEnum)),
                "\"ANALYZE\"".FromJson<TestEnum>(),
                (TestEnum)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("\"ANALYZE\"", typeof(TestEnum)),
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEnum>("\"ANALYZE\"")
            }.Each(testEnum => Assert.AreEqual(testEnum, TestEnum.Analyze));




            new List<Test>
            {
                "{\"PropertyTest\":\"ANALYZE\",\"PropertyString\":\"ANALYZE\"}".FromJson<Test>(),
                (Test)ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString("{\"PropertyTest\":\"ANALYZE\",\"PropertyString\":\"ANALYZE\"}", typeof(Test)),
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>("{\"PropertyTest\":\"ANALYZE\",\"PropertyString\":\"ANALYZE\"}"),
                (Test)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"PropertyTest\":\"ANALYZE\",\"PropertyString\":\"ANALYZE\"}",typeof(Test))
            }.Each(test =>
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(test.PropertyTest, TestEnum.Analyze);
                Assert.AreEqual(test.PropertyString, "ANALYZE");
            });





        }

        [Test]
        public void Serialisations()
        {



            Assert.AreEqual("{\"PropertyTest\":\"ANALYZE\",\"PropertyString\":\"ANALYZE\"}", new Test { PropertyTest = TestEnum.Analyze, PropertyString = TestEnum.Analyze }.ToJson());
            Assert.AreEqual("{\"PropertyTest\":\"ANALYZE\",\"PropertyString\":\"ANALYZE\"}", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Test { PropertyTest = TestEnum.Analyze, PropertyString = TestEnum.Analyze }));
            Assert.AreEqual("\"ANALYZE\"", TestEnum.Analyze.ToJson());
            Assert.AreEqual("\"ANALYZE\"", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TestEnum.Analyze));
        }


        [Test]
        public void TestEnums()
        {

            Assert.AreEqual(TestEnum.All.Count(), 2);
            Assert.Contains(TestEnum.Analyze,TestEnum.All.ToList());
            Assert.Contains(TestEnum.Test,TestEnum.All.ToList());

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't comment on the `Json` stuff, as it doesn't seem to be the main subject to the question.

I'm not sure, I quite understand where to use this, so if you have a concrete real use case feel free to update the question with it.

You can't for instance use it in a switch like:

```
  TestEnum te = TestEnum.Analyze;

  switch (te)
  {
    case TestEnum.Analyze:
      Console.WriteLine("Analyze");
      break;
    case TestEnum.Test:
      Console.WriteLine("Test");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
```

because the-enum properties aren't constant.

You can do:

```
  TestEnum te = TestEnum.Analyze;

  switch (te)
  {
    case TestEnum t when t == TestEnum.Analyze:
      Console.WriteLine("Analyze");
      break;
    case TestEnum t when t == TestEnum.Test:
      Console.WriteLine("Test");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
```

but IMO that may be tedious in the long run.

---

The overall impression is, that your cast system is messy. Trying to debug it to find a way for a string or an enum value is confusing, and you (I) easily lose track of the path. IMO you rely too heavily on casting to and from `string`.

---

Be aware, that this:

> `public static TestEnum Analyze { get { return new EnumType<TestEnum>("ANALYZE"); } }`

is different than this:

```
public static TestEnum Analyze { get; } = new EnumType<TestEnum>("ANALYZE");
```

Where the first returns a new instance of `Analyze` for every call, the latter only instantiates one the first time it is called - just like a static (readonly) property or field should behave. Related to that, I think that each "enum"-property should be a singleton, and only instantiated once. You instantiate various instances of each property in the cast methods. I don't like that. Further I think, I would make the constructor of `TestEnum` private to prevent unauthorized instantiation of invalid enum values. If you make the constructor private, you can't specify `T` with the constraint `new()`. But that is OK, if you make each `enum` value a singleton - only instantiated where defined.

---

As for the initialization of the static enum-properties it goes for `All`:

> ```
> public static IEnumerable<T> All
>  => typeof(T).GetProperties()
>    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T))
>    .Select(x => (T)x.GetValue(null, null));
> ```

where

```
public static IReadOnlyList<T> All { get; } = 
  typeof(T).GetProperties()
  .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T))
  .Select(x => (T)x.GetValue(null, null))
  .ToList();
```

will be much more efficient as reflection is only activated once. Notice that I've changed `IEnumerable<T>` to `IReadOnlyList<T>` in order to cache the query. Repeatedly using reflection may be a bottleneck - especially if you have many enum-properties.

---

You can and should narrow down the properties searched for by using `BindingFlags` in `All`:

```
typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)...
```

---

> ```
>     public override bool Equals(object obj)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             if(obj.GetType() == typeof(string))
>             {
>                 return Value == (string)obj;
>             }
>
>             return Value == obj as T;
>         }
>         catch(Exception ex)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
> ```

This seems overly complicated and a catch block here is unnecessary:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj is T other) return ReferenceEquals(this, other) || Value == other.Value;
  return obj is string value && Value == value;
}
```

---

Here:

> ```
>     public static implicit operator EnumType<T>(string s)
>     {
>         if (All.Any(dt => dt.Value == s))
>         {
>             return new T { Value = s };
>         }
> ```

I think, I would do:

```
public static implicit operator EnumType<T>(string s)
{
  if (All.FirstOrDefault(dt => dt.Value == s) is T e)
  {
    return e;
  }
  else
```

In this way, the already created enum is reused.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your input I used it and wanted to do a proper reply but never got the time...

It does seem alambicated but there are many case where I have a string (for instance coming from an api) and want to compare it with an enum.  

I finally found some place where they used the same kind of approach:
 https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/pull/1595/commits/4cf1ca8b590467134afaf3c0a396f3b15be63c59#diff-62a4dbc88828864f79581a1184638a7c

I might switch to something more like them. (not sure about the serialisation though).